# Model evaluation via k-fold-cross validation after variable selection

Tags: cross-validation, model-evaluation, out-of-sample

I am currently trying to implement some methods (OLS, GLM) and compare their predictive accuracy. For that I want to perform variable selection for each of the methods and then measure the predictive accuracy of each of the final models with metrics like MAE/RAE/RMSE...

So at first I thought it is done the following way: I split my data set into training and test set, do the variable selection on the training data and then evaluate the model on the test data by calculation MAE/RAE/RMSE on the test data set.

Now, what got me confused is an approach I saw quite often in some really high-ranked journals. They do variable selection on the full data set via AIC. Now with the selected variables, they perform k-fold-CV on the full data set again and evaluate their model by calculating MAE/RAE/RMSE inside the k-fold-CV.

I always thought that when doing variable selection, you NEED to hold away a test set to evaluate the model. What they do in the papers I read is entirely different. They perform variable selection on the full data set and then use k-fold-cv on the whole data set again to evaluate the model. Is this really a statistical valid approach (I guess so, because the journals are really high-ranked). If it is, why would you ever do option one (train/test-split) as performance metrics calculated by k-fold-cv are more robust than testing out-of-sample one single time.

I would really appreciate if someone could comment on that.

Edit: For example see sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221716001004. On p. 915 they write "To assess the out-of-sample performance of the models thoroughly, 10-fold cross validation was conducted on the entire sample of accounts" and they indeed did variable selection in each of the models as first step.

Comment: Are they statistics journals? What you describe them doing is not that way to do it as you are biasing your estimate of generalization error, maybe you misunderstood what they did, or more likely just did it wrong.

Comment: These are quantitative finance journals. For example see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377221716001004. On p. 915 they write "To assess the out-of-sample performance of the models thoroughly, 10-fold cross validation was conducted on the entire sample of accounts" and they indeed did variable selection in each of the models as first step.

What I dont really understand is why it biases the estimate of generalization error. Because I could just happen to "guess" the variables the model performs best with and then do k-fold-CV to assess the out-of-sample performance.

Comment: 1)Think about this example from (from the book The Elements of Statistical Learning I think). You have 1000 variables and 100 records. Your 1000 variables are all iid random variables and the response variable is a binary random variable with a 50% chance of being a 1. The response variable is independent of all your predictor variables such that the true prediction error is 50%. Now before cross validation you decide to do variable selection to find the 10 variables that are most correlated with the response variable. Then you perform cross-validation and find you get an error rate near 0

Comment: 2)The problem is that even though you did cross-validation you introduced bias by using the entire dataset to do variable selection and thus found some spurious correlations that don't actually exist in the population. On why this matters since you could have just guessed the correct variables, well guessing the correct variables would have lead to a an incorrect estimate of the generalization error as well, you just wouldn't have known that it might be biased. Which is why, without subject matter knowledge, it is probably a bad idea to just guess.

Comment: 3)On the paper, with only taking a quick look through, it looks like the authors use stepwise methods for OLS which is commonly thought of as poor form. It looks like the authors just don't really know what they are doing. Which is not that surprising even in a top journal,after all, universities are still teaching things like stepwise regression.